# Android: Add entry to the calendar

Tags: android

I am trying to add entry to the calendar,but it threwn error.

Source code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("title", "test");
        intent.putExtra("description", "Popis");
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Somewhere");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis () + 60 * 60 * 1000);
        intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis () + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Sorry for my English i am beginner.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: I already solved this problem.

Comment: to increase your reputation post an answer of your solution.  then you can accept it as the correct answer.  and we will all have the benefit of the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the [WRITE_CALENDAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_CALENDAR) [use-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) in your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)